# Big O Definition

Tags: asymptotics

There is a formal definition for the Big O notation in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation). Up to now I have come across Big O in Numerical Analysis, Calculus and Algorithms which all are pretty distinct fields. What I am wondering is if that definition is global and is the only one that is used in every field where the Big O is involved or there are other ways that the Big O is defined in other areas  of Mathematics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most general definition on Wikipedia, which is that of saying
$$
f\in O(g)\text{ as }x\rightarrow a
$$
whenever
$$
\limsup_{x\rightarrow a}\left|\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\right|<\infty
$$
is the standard one used in all fields.

The relevant case in computer science is $a=\infty$. Moreover, by
convention, $x$ usually takes integer values, and is hence written
$n$. For example,
$$
2n^{2}+3n+1\in O(n^{2})\text{ as }n\rightarrow\infty.
$$
Since it is understood that $a=\infty$, one usually does not specify
$n\rightarrow\infty$ in the notation.

In numerical analysis, one usually cares about approximating a function
at a point $x$ using the information encoded by the smoothness of
the function at a point $a$. For example, $e^{x}$ is approximately
$1+x$ as $x\rightarrow0$:
$$
e^{x}-(1+x)\in O(x^{2})\text{ as }x\rightarrow0.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Writing form $\left|\dfrac{f(x)}{g(x)}\right|$ makes impossible to consider function $g$, for which point $a$(from $x\rightarrow a$) is a limit point for $g$'s zeros.

The big majority of books, where I saw big-O, contains 1'st definition from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation), not last with limit superior.

If somebody want to create unify definition, **the most general**, for several types of limit point, then, possibly, is more good to use the concept of topological neighbourhood of $a$, $U(a)$:

$O(g) =  \left\lbrace f:\exists C > 0,\ \exists U(a),\  \forall x \in U(a),\  (\left|f(x)\right| \leqslant C \cdot \left|g(x)\right|) \right\rbrace $